# SRTM raster looks pixelated with hillshade style in QGIS when zooming in

Tags: qgis, raster, resampling, srtm

I have a project and I want to create a map using SRTM as a background.
I upload it ... and it looks like that: [image: general view]

But my project area is smaller, so I need to zoom it ... and when I do that, my SRTM looks like that: [image]

What can I do so the raster doesn't look so pixelated?

Answer (score 5):

Hillshade is only as good as the quality (resolution) of the underlying DEM. What you can do is changing the resampling mode from `Nearest Neighbour` (default) to `Bilinear` (recommended for elevation/hillshade) or `Cubic`. You find these settings in Layer Styling Panel / Symbology at the bottom.

See this [explanation about the difference between Nearest Neighbor, Bilinear Interpolation and Cubic  resampling](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005606) for the theoretical background - the principle is the same in QGIS as in ESRI software. Short version:

> Nearest Neighbor can be used on continuous data but the results can be blocky.(...) Bilinear Interpolation uses a weighted average of the four nearest
> cell centers. (...) it should be used for continuous data like
> elevation and raw slope values.

See also [What is Bilinear Interpolation?](https://gisgeography.com/bilinear-interpolation-resampling/)

*Enlarged section from the screenshot below - left: resampling mode `Nearest Neighbour`, right: `Bilinear`:*

[image]

[image]

*See here the settings and the result:*
[image]

Comment: When you enable "Early resampling" you get more options for resampling, I highly recommend Cubic Spline for nice looking hillshading when zoomed in to coarse DEMs.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are rendering the DEM as a Hillshade which is the part resulting in the pixellating.

I don't know why but when zooming on DEM layers with a Hillshade Style rendering in QGIS, it is made of uniform grey pixels with graduated contour lines as pictured below

a) Raw DEM (Singleband Pseudocolor):
[image]

b) Hillshade rendering when zoomed in:
[image]

I would recommend you to:

1. reproject the SRTM DEM to your project CRS:
   [image]
   with Hillshade rendering there is still an unexpected rendering when zoomed in but there are no aliasing effects
2. use the Processing Toolbox>GDAL>Raster Analysis>Hillshade to create a new Hillshade layer:[image]
   By being reprojected there are no aliasing effects and being a native Hillshade layer, each pixel has the actual hillshade value

With that, and depending on what you specifically want to achieve, you shoudl be good